# What can make pip lie about a successful install?

Tags: python, pip

I have a script which does

```
mkvirtualenv foo
pip install -r foo/requirements.txt || abort_with_error_message
pip freeze
```

The pip install says

```
Successfully installed <List of packages>
```

Where the list of packages includes everything in the requirements.txt.  But the `pip freeze` lists fewer packages.  In particular, `gevent-1.4.0` is in the requirements and the "successfully installed", but not the freeze, the `~/.virualenvs/foo/*/dist-packages` or the things I can import.  There's nothing there.

Adding -vvv to pip install reveals nothing useful.

There's got to be something really weird in my environment to be triggering this, but I don't know where to look.  What could possibly make pip announce the successful installation of packages it never actually installed?

Edit to Add:

I can make this problem go away by using

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

instead of

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash -i
```

in the script.  (My .bashrc contains the source virtualenvwrapper line.)

I'm stumped as to why this matters.  The only other things my .bashrc does are set some unrelated variables, add a few things to the path, and invoke /etc/bashrc (AWS GNU/Linux, forked from CentOS).

Comment: So, can you `import gevent` or not?

Comment: @wim No.  I cannot import it.  As I said, it is not among the things I can import (second to last line of the first full paragraph).

Comment: Did you activate the virtual environment? In your provided info its not showing `source foo/bin/activate` before the `pip install`.

Comment: I tried adding that.  No effect.  mkvirtualenv does it automatically, so that's not a surprise.   And other packages from the requirements file do show up in the virtualenv

Comment: Do you get the same problem without using virtualenvwrapper (just use virtualenv directly)? Let's remove some unnecessary complexity here.

Comment: Just tried, same exact problem.  Thanks for the idea, though.